# Replacing a symbolic link after replacing target

Tags: symlink

If I have a symbolic link to a target file and I replace the target file's data, keeping the same target name, do I have to delete the symbolic link and create it again ?

Comment: Isn't this something you can easily try yourself?

Answer (score 1):

No.  A symbolic link only refers to the target's name/path, not the contents.